# Warning CA1031 Modify '' to catch a more specific exception than 'Exception' or rethrow the exception

Tags: .net, exception, c#-6.0

Below code is written in C#6. Is this a specific exception handling?

```
catch (Exception e) when (e is NullReferenceException || e is InvalidOperationException)
{
    //Log exception
}
```

Earlier my code was

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Log exception
}
```

at that time I got warning

> Warning   CA1031  Modify '' to catch a more specific exception than
>   'Exception' or rethrow the exception" on code analysis.

Answer (score 2):

The general problem with catching `Exception` and letting your code carry on is it could have been *anything*. You no longer know what state the rest of the program is in. The problem with your more specific exception filters (so far as I'm concerned) is that you're catching exceptions that are *programming errors* and so again, shouldn't allow the program to continue running since clearly you're in *unanticipated* areas.

In general, I'd advise having a single unhandled exception handler installed at the appropriate top level (what that is depends on which application framework you're building in, but usually won't be represented by an actual `catch` block) that logs before exiting. Anywhere else you have exception handlers should be for *specific* exceptions for which you have a *specific* recovery strategy. Null references and Invalid operations are unlikely to fit in this latter category.

Comment: Null references and Invalid operations are just example. My question is can I use "when" with catch block to catch some specific exception?

Answer (score 2):

It is specific.
Idea is similar to

```
catch (NullReferenceException e)
{
    //Log exception
}
catch(InvalidOperationException e)
{
    //Log exception
}
```

which is specific.

CA1031 covers only one of N cases of its kind. The global idea is to catch as specific exception as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using Throw:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Log exception
    throw;
}
```